# SSL encrypted Websockets in Java Using Java WebSockets API

Tags: java, ssl, websocket

So, I have been using the [Java Websockets API](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket) to create a WebSocket server in Java, which worked just fine, until I realized I should be using an SSL encrypted connection using "wss:myurl.tld". Basically, the API wants an SSLContext object to work with SSL, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to make one of those.

I looked at some examples and found out that if I could make a Java KeyStore file with a certificate I could make it work, so I tried to do that.

I started fiddling around with trying to get a "Let's Encrypt" certificate following [these instructions](https://maximilian-boehm.com/hp2121/Create-a-Java-Keystore-JKS-from-Let-s-Encrypt-Certificates.htm) but I ran into to some problems.

1. I run windows and I could find no software using the Let's Encrypt system that worked the same as in the instructions, and homebrew on my mac machine is broken, and it's running a too old OS to update.
2. Being rather inexperienced with SSL I had no real idea what to put in as parameters.

So, in short, how do I make my Java Websocket server use a secure SSL connection?

Oh, and pardon my messy English and lack of question-writing skills, I'm a bit new to these sorts of things.